# Unable to boot into recovery after flashing TWRP

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, motorola-moto-g

My phone model: Moto G Falcon

I flashed TWRP with the app. I am not able to boot into recovery mode. I get this error message:

> Invalid boot image size!
>
> failed to validate recovery image

I am stuck with Cyanogenmod12 Nightly. The thing is I am at least able to boot my phone.

Comment: If you had TWRP installed previously, you can install zip using twrp itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install ADB tools for your distribution. Check if it works with:

```
fastboot devices
```

then install with:

```
fastboot flash recovery twrp*.img
```

For me, the installation via the TWRP app did not work and I flashed it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you might have installed a TWRP image that was not for your phone or corrupt. I would download it again, making sure it is the correct version, that is, it is the one for falcon and flash it again by booting in fastboot mode (power + vol down), and use

```
fastboot flash recovery twrp-3.2.1-0-falcon.img
```

Modify the name of the .img file accordingly.